# How to prove law of the iterated logarithm

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The law of the iterated logarithm is stated as below:
Let $X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables with mean zero and unit variance. Define$ S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i $. Then, almost surely:
$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2 n \log{\log\ n}}} = 1$.

I can derive the conclusion when $X_n$ have Normal distribution. But my attempt to prove the original one has failed, and I didn't find related articles as well. It will be much appreciated if anyone can provide some related articles or hints.

Answer (score 1):

I think the full proof is quite involved (uses SLLN).

Here's a weaker statement. If you consider
$$
E_n = I_{|\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2 n \log \log n}}| <1}
$$
then
$$
P(E_n) = P( -1 \leq \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2 n \log \log n}} \leq 1) = P(-\sqrt{2 \log \log n}\leq \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\leq \sqrt{2 \log \log n}) = \Phi(\sqrt{2 \log \log n}) - \Phi(-\sqrt{2 \log \log n}) \to_n 1-0 = 1
$$
which is convergence in probability.